# Ping and nslookup work, but connection is refused

Tags: networking, google-chrome, dns, ping

As per the question title, my PC repeatedly loses the ability to connect to websites despite `ping` and `nslookup` functioning correctly. The PC will run normally for anywhere between 15 and 60 minutes after booting before the problem occurs.

I've tested this in Google Chrome, Edge, and Internet Explorer. In Chrome, I'm still able to connect to `youtube.com`, and to `google.com` and its various subdomains; in Edge and IE, even these sites refuse to connect. I've checked Chrome's DNS cache, and can confirm that Chrome is getting the correct IP addresses, it's just not connecting to them.

I've run scans with both Avast Free and malwarebytes, and neither has shown any evidence of viruses or malware on my system. Help would be greatly appreciated!

**What does work**

- `nslookup` of a given domain name
- `ping`, whether by domain name or IP address
- connecting to `google.com` subdomains and `youtube.com` via Google Chrome

**What doesn't work**

- connecting to any websites other than `google.com`/`youtube.com` in Google Chrome, whether by domain name or IP address
- connecting to any websites at all in MS Edge/Internet Explorer, whether by domain name or IP address
- connecting to my router by IP address

Comment: Does rebooting the router restore access?

Comment: @MarkoPolo It hasn't so far, have tried a couple of times

Comment: Ok, would you possibly be able to get a Wireshark capture the next time that happens, showing the successful ping to some website and the subsequent failure to connect through a browser?

Comment: Roger, will do - although it hasn't happened at all this evening, so who knows what's going on...